# JavaScript dateTime string to seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to take a value from HTML div field that is long date in this format: "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss (am/pm)".
So I get the value, and what I want to do is to convert that value (which is string) into seconds, and preview it in a alert box?
I tried with this code, but it shows NaN

```
        myDivObj = document.getElementById("date").innerHTML;
        var a = myDivObj.split('/');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);

        alert(seconds);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you doing with the hours and seconds?  your calculation seems to only deal with the months days and years - so `a[2]` would be in the form of `YY hh:mm(am/pm)`.  Also you have no seconds in that time so what is the formula you are using?  Are you only wanting to use the hours and minutes part of the date?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the seconds in the format. basically what i want to do is have a counter that counts down the rest of the dates, and the counter i use must have the date into seconds... but probably i will change the counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from W3Schools JavaScript [Date object's reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

> Date.parse()
>
> Parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds since
> midnight of January 1, 1970

Divide that by 1000 and you get the seconds.

```
var string = TextInput.value;
var seconds = (Date.parse(string)) / 1000;
alert("Seconds: "+seconds);
```

Comment: MDN Please! W3Schools.com is slow to update material on its site...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Great! I didn't know about the Mozilla pages, guess I'll stick to them now. This is gold!

Answer (score 0):

try using parseInt() to create numbers from the strings that is the output from the .split() function

```
    myDivObj = document.getElementById("date").innerHTML;
    var a = myDivObj.split('/');
    var seconds = parseInt(a[0]) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(a[1]) * 60 + parseInt(a[2]);

    alert(seconds);
```

here is a fiddle (in jQuery, I'm not much of an 'au natural' guy)
http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/sZ9Gz/1/